# Why the responsive concepts are included in Flat Design?

Tags: responsive-design, user-experience, flat

I am a noob in UX design concepts. Recently I gone through one article about flat design, where they stated that Responsive is so much cared. Usually , when i develop sites, i always tries to make a responsive site. What i want to know is , maximum of people always want their sites to be work in all kind of devices, so that they are giving much importance for responsive design irrespective of the design technique that they follow to build sites. So responsive concepts are common.so why the responsive concepts are included in flat design ?

Comment: responsive concepts included in flat design?flat design is more like UI concept and resposive-UX. They both are totally different concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every new client these days wants a mobile version of their website. It’s practically essential after all: one design for the BlackBerry, another for the iPhone, the iPad, net-book, Kindle — and all screen resolutions must be compatible, too.

In the next five years, we’ll likely need to design for a number of additional inventions. When will the madness stop? It won’t, of course. That's why it's refer to have responsive User Interface.

I hope answer the question.